# Where are the settings of a Windows 8 App stored?

Tags: windows-8

Like the title says, I'm looking for the path where the settings of a Windows 8 App are stored.

I already found out that it is **not** the path where the app itself is stored (*C:\Program Files\WindowsApps*)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found it on my own, they are saved at

> C:/Users/**Username**/AppData/Local/Packages/**Appname**/Settings

Comment: I should point out this is actually the case with a normal desktop application also.  Of course some developers ignore this guidance from Microsoft.  The good news is applications from the Windows 8 Store will all have to follow this guidance.