# Where are Modern UI apps saving their settings?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are the settings of a Windows 8 App stored?](https://superuser.com/questions/468249/where-are-the-settings-of-a-windows-8-app-stored)

Where are Modern UI apps saving their settings?

In registry? Or a per-app file?

I'm asking because I wonder if installing a ton of them will cause registry rot

Answer (score 1):

There is no definitive answer, in the newer version of .Net they are stored in settings.settings files which are internal to the application.

They can also be stored in the registry.

They can also be stored at:
`C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Packages/Appname/Settings`